# Firebase: return value from function(snapshot)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the return value people, and to use it.

if I am doing var `somthing = function(snapshot){` inside the `.on` it is crashed saying the second value should be function.

I can not give up the `orderBy` and only do

```
var results = function(snapshot)
```

Here is my code.

How do I get the people value?

```
peopleDataBase.orderByChild("mCalculateFaceSizeWidth")
                        .startAt(mCalculateFaceSizeWidth())
                        .limitToFirst(1)
                        .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                         var person = {
                                "name":snapshot.val().name,
                                "age":snapshot.val().age,
                                "id":snapshot.val().id,
                                "children":snapshot.val().children,
                                "address":snapshot.val().address,
                                "image":snapshot.val().image
                             }

                             if(key != snapshot.key){
                                people += person;
                                key = snapshot.key;

                                 }
                            return people;
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you returned the value as a parameter to the .on function which caused the error. Try this (for more info: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html):

```
var result = peopleDataBase.orderByChild("mCalculateFaceSizeWidth")
                    .startAt(mCalculateFaceSizeWidth())
                    .limitToFirst(1)
                    .on("value").then(function(snapshot) {

                         //This forEach brings at most one node
                         snapshot.forEach(snapshotChild){

                           var person = {
                               "name":snapshotChild.val().name,
                               "age":snapshotChild.val().age,
                               "id":snapshotChild.val().id,
                               "children":snapshotChild.val().children,
                               "address":snapshotChild.val().address,
                               "image":snapshotChild.val().image
                            }

                            if(key != snapshotChild.key){
                                people += person;
                                key = snapshotChild.key;
                            }
                         }
                         return people;
                       });
```

Comment: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
snapshot.forEach(snapshotChild){
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: I made a typo snapshot.forEach(function(snapshotChild){

Comment: I fixed few more thing in your example
but the results are the actual search 
//This forEach brings at most one node
                            snapshot.forEach(function(snapshotChild){

                                var person = {
                                    "name":snapshotChild.val().name,
                                    "age":snapshotChild.val().age,
for example on("value").then(function(snapshot) does not work either.
.On expect two arg and in your example only 1

Comment: Now I understand the example you gave me, I saw this in the node js example.
But my code does not run on client it runs directly on the cloud with cloud functions so something like .on("value").then(function(snapshot)
Just does not work.

Comment: Well I still need help, how do I return the people value, basically I wanted to return it with the response back to the mobile client.

Comment: I am using the admin SDK, it does not work on the cloud functions if you are not using it.

Comment: Look at this page 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data
you see all the examples are console.log examples 
They did not once say return the snapshot.val();

Comment: These are all client based 
When execute the ref on it execute 
asynchronous callback to read the data at their posts reference
When you doing from the cloud and trying to do return value at the end of the function it returns undefined because it does not wait for the task to complete there for I am not able to return the object back to the client.
So I wanted to return the value directly from the snapshot function
This way I am making sure the data retrieved before moving forward 
and return the object back to the mobile device.

Comment: In your sample, after fixing I am not getting error but I am not getting the value.
I am getting the entire ref as a text ...
"peopleDataBase.orderByChild("mCalculateFaceSizeWidth")....."

Comment: Would you look at Promises are Composable section of that https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html ?